# Wordpress website showing IP instead the domain?

Tags: wordpress

I have WordPress website on google cloud and it is sometimes showing my Ip Adress instead the domain. Some parts of the website are working fine with the domain but others like search and subdomains are showing the IP instead of my domain.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You probably need https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: Please post a link to your site so people can poke around. You'll get better answers that way.

Comment: Hi Tim. It is http://planeeurope.com/ if you go there and click in one of the links like "Piston Single" you will see that the next page will be a page with the IP address instead of the domain.

Comment: Hi Tim. Do you saw my last message?

Comment: I see the issue on http://planeeurope.com/pricing-plans/ on all "More Info" Buttons for example. Are you sure the wordpress page is having the domain name instead of the IP address in the content?

Comment: I corrected that. The link was with the IP instead the domain. Rookie mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings on WordPress dashboard -> general settings -> change the site url with the url of your website hope it helps do you have access to wp_config.php file try this

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://your_site_url.com');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://your_site_url.com');
```

Comment: It is already set with my url. Look the website works with the url. Just some pages like searches are showing the IP instead the URL

Comment: @LeonardoFornasier Did you find an answer ?